# Does a gravitational wave let my coffee spill?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves

An observer holds a cup of coffee that is filled to the brim at the moment a gravitational wave passes by.
Should the observer be worried about spilling coffee because of the
gravitational wave? If so, could we estimate the maximum height that the observer can fill his cup to avoid spilling the coffee?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338912/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168274/

Comment: Could you elaborate? I do not find a clear answer in the "related" posts.

Comment: They're not duplicates, but similar questions have been asked about roughly what a person would feel if a strong enough gravitational wave went past.

Comment: LIGO has detected 14 gravitational waves. None of them spilled *my* coffee.

Comment: @G.Smith, Maybe you just weren't sitting close enough to the black holes. Maybe next time, pull up your chair to within a couple of light years of the stage, and see how your beverage fares then.

Comment: Maybe, but I don’t see anything in the question about where I need to be. Just something about my head which I didn’t understand.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passing wave will not spill your coffee. Simply because it transforms the cup **including** the coffee inside it in the same way. No movement of the coffee will be observed, no matter how strong the wave. Of course, if the wave has an enormous intensity, the cup will probably break, and **all** your coffee is spilled! So don't go living near two circulating black holes with masses comparable to the mass of the black hole in the center of most galaxies...

Comment: Great answer! Combined with the related questions, it solved my question.

Comment: @drandran12  I just finished eating. Great to hear this! Thanks!